# Finding the Nearest Points - Optimize

Tags: sql, postgresql, location, postgis

The following SQL query is almost the most used part of the project. It works exactly as I wanted but, its cost `(cost=11835.77..11835.82 rows=21 width=137)` is too high and it consumes server resources.

```sql
SELECT
  "companies"."id",
  "companies"."name",
  MIN(
    ST_Distance(
      addresses.location,
      ST_SetSRID(ST_Point(28.9856799, 41.0842721), 4326)
    )
  ) as distance
from
  "companies"
  left join "branches" on "companies"."id" = "branches"."company_id"
  and "branches"."active" = true
  inner join "addresses" on "branches"."id" = "addresses"."addressable_id"
  and "addresses"."addressable_type" = 'App\Domains\Company\Models\Branch'
where
  "available" = true
group by
  "companies"."id"
order by
  "distance" asc
limit
  21 offset 0;
```

If I had to explain briefly; Every company has many branches. I keep the locations of the branches in the `addresses` table. My aim is to list the companies closest to the sent point by paginating.

The cost `(cost=0.57..23.12 rows=21 width=137)` of the following query is very low, but companies with more than one branch come as duplicates. But the company must be listed as singular.

```sql
select
  "companies"."id",
  "companies"."name"
from
  "companies"
  left join "branches" on "branches"."company_id" = "companies"."id"
  left join "addresses" on "addresses"."addressable_id" = "branches"."id"
where
  "addresses"."addressable_type" = 'App\Domains\Company\Models\Branch'
  and "branches"."active" = true
  and "available" = true
order by
  "addresses"."location" <-> ST_SetSRID(ST_Point(28.9856799, 41.0842721), 4326)
limit
  21 offset 0
```

I am using PostgreSQL 13 and PostGIS as database.

You can find sample data [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gC35KMyEePYRZLk5T1qQkk/2).

The result I want to see exactly;

```
 id |      name       
----+-----------------
  1 | Apple
 13 | Volvo
  9 | Burger King
 18 | Sunexpress
 11 | Togg
 19 | MC Donalds
 14 | THY
 16 | Lufthansa
  6 | Migros
  5 | Carrefour
  4 | Starbucks
  3 | Apartment
 10 | Tesla
  2 | Coffee
 17 | Pegasus
 22 | LG
 15 | British Airways
 12 | Volkswagen
 21 | Samsung
 20 | KFC
  7 | Google
```

Comment: [`<->` operator](https://postgis.net/docs/geometry_distance_knn.html) makes use of spatial indexes in the `ORDER BY` clause while [ST_Distance](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Distance.html) does not since it will do a sequence scan and calculate the distance from each point in a table.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of calculating the distance of all records to the given geometries in order to find the shortest distance, just use the distance operator `<->` as [Jim Jones](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2275388/jim-jones) said.

---

So change this lines

```sql
MIN(
    ST_Distance(
      addresses.location,
      ST_SetSRID(ST_Point(28.9856799, 41.0842721), 4326)
    )
  ) as distance
```

to

```sql
MIN(ST_SetSRID(ST_Point(28.9856799, 41.0842721), 4326) <-> addresses.location) AS distance
```

this in select list.

```sql
SELECT
    "companies"."id",
    "companies"."name",
    MIN(ST_SetSRID (ST_Point (28.9856799, 41.0842721), 4326) <-> addresses.location) AS distance
FROM
    "companies"
    LEFT JOIN "branches" ON "companies"."id" = "branches"."company_id"
        AND "branches"."active" = TRUE
    INNER JOIN "addresses" ON "branches"."id" = "addresses"."addressable_id"
        AND "addresses"."addressable_type" = 'App\Domains\Company\Models\Branch'
GROUP BY
    "companies"."id"
ORDER BY
    "distance" ASC
LIMIT 21 OFFSET 0;
```

This query cost is `(cost=183.36..183.42 rows=21 width=30)`